# How can I create a temporary file using Java FileChooser?

Tags: java, javafx, nio

I got the following method which creates a file:

```
public static File cuadroDialogoGuardarTorrent (String pelicula) {

    ventanaGuardar.setInitialFileName(pelicula+".torrent");
    ventanaGuardar.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Downloads"));
    ventanaGuardar.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Archivo torrent de descarga", "*.torrent")
    ); 

    File archivo = ventanaGuardar.showSaveDialog(null);

    if (archivo == null) return null;


    return archivo;
}
```

`ventanaGuardar` is a **JavaFX** `FileChooser`.

After the reference `File` is returned, I download some binary and write it to the file using this **`NIO`** methods:

```
URL website = new URL(url);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(torrent);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

And that's when File is actually *created*, how can I make, however that File *temporal* or *delete on close*?

Comment: By deleting it when you're done using it?  http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-file-in-java/

Comment: I need it to exist for a little time

Comment: Then delete it after that little time elapses.  Or, hook the "close" event or whatever on your UI, and delete it then.

Comment: As I know NIO can do temporal Files, but I'm obtaining that File from FileChooser then through it's OutputStream I write it ..- I'd like to know how to make it temporal, on the go.

Comment: Why don't you just use [createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) )?

Answer (score 2):

Given your `File archivo` and stated requirement, I would use [deleteOnExit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29). That is,

```
archivo.deleteOnExit();
```